# Given the probability density function what is the most probable value of r

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, quantum-mechanics

The wavefunction of the lowest energy state of hydrogen is $$
\psi(r) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi a_0^3}}e^{-r/a_0}$$ and the probability density is $$\frac{1}{\pi a_0^3}e^{-2r/a_0}$$ where $r$ is the radial distance between electron and nucleus and $a_0$ is the Bohr radius.

To find the most probable value of $r$, do I differentiate w.r.t. $r$ to find the maximum of the probability density function? Or differentiate twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "most probable value" of a density function is supposed to mean the point in which the most mass is located. You are looking for the most probable value of $r$ so you need to translate your probability density, which right now is a density on $\mathbb R^3$ to a density on $\mathbb R_{≥0}$, ie the space of radii.

In this case this is sort of simple, the condition is:
$$\int_{r_a}^{r_b} p_r(r)\ dr=\int_{B_{r_b}(0)-B_{r_a}(0)}p(x,y,z)\ dV=\int_{r_a}^{r_b}4\pi r^2 \frac1{\pi a_0^3}e^{-2r/a_0}\ dr$$
And you see how you must include a $4\pi r^2$ term.

So explicitly you need to find the value of $r$ where
$$\frac{4r^2}{a_0^3}e^{-2r/a_0}$$
is maximal. Since this function is smooth, you can differentiate it to find the local extrema. If you do this you will find that the maximal value is at $a_0$.

Comment: Wow, ok. Is that line of working using Stoke's or Green's theorem or something like that? Looks vaguely familiar

Comment: @Karacoreable Not really. I'm not sure which part you mean, but the transformation of the space is in essence the following idea:
If you have a (measurable) function from $X$ to $Y$ and a probability measure $\mu$ on $X$, then the probability that the value of $f$ lies in a set $E\subset Y$ is
$$\int_{f^{-1}(E)}d\mu =: \int_E df_*(\mu)$$
(Think about why this formula correctly describes that probability.) So you induce another probability measure on $Y$. Here our spaces are $\mathbb R^3$ and $\mathbb R_{≥0}$ with $f$ being $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.

Comment: If you mean the part about finding the point where the most mass is located, here there are some more subtleties. You need to have a way of assigning volume to the parameter space, because saying "most of the mass is located around this point" depends on how you give areas around that point volume. In $\mathbb R^n$ it is usual to consider the point $x$ where the following expression is made maximal:
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac1{\mathrm{Vol}(B_\epsilon(x))}\int_{B_\epsilon(x)}p\ dV$$